# Reputation page doesn't show breakdown for more than 2 days ago

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

I performed a reputation recalc and my reputation dropped 50 points. Not knowing why that should be, I went to my reputation page and noticed that daily reputation was shown, but the triangles were not there to show the reputation breakdown for more than 2 days ago.

The graph does not show up on the graph page either; just a blank area where the graph might go.

Yesterday, I was looking through my reputation broken down daily to see when I had been awarded bounties, so the daily breakdowns were available yesterday. I would really like to know why I lost 50 points, and why the reputation breakdown is not currently available.

Here are a couple of screenshots:

[image: reputation list]

Note that there are no expansion buttons (triangles) next to the daily totals for Jan 7 - Jan 15.  The expansion buttons next to Jan 16 - yesterday are inactive (nothing happens when they are clicked).

[image: reputation graph]

There is no graph displayed.

**Possible Resolution:** After updating Firefox to 9.0.1, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a screenshot depicting the problem..?

Comment: I checked my own and I don't have the problem... Curioser and curioser.

Comment: @Arturo: I updated my Firefox from 3.5.15 to 9.0.1, and now things are back to normal. Perhaps the site is using some web features not supported by Firefox 3.5.15 (two years old).

Comment: @robjohn: Perhaps you should post that as an answer so that this can be "closed", then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated my Firefox from 3.5.15 to 9.0.1 and now the reputation pages are back to normal.  Perhaps those pages have been updated recently to use some features not supported by the two-year-old Firefox 3.5.15.

I am seeing the same thing again. This time, I am running Firefox 9.0.1, so apparently the association with Firefox 3.5.15 was erroneous.

**Update:**

This has occurred periodically, but it usually goes away within a day.

Comment: Oy vey, 3.5.15?!

Comment: Considering the number of internet users who still use IE6, that's not so bad.

Comment: That is quite the upgrade!

Comment: 10k in four months? Nicely done.